# How to ask user input from flask (I'm using react for front end)?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I already got some input into the `flask` from the forms using the `fetch API` POST method. Now depending on this input, I want to ask some more inputs `(without rendering a new HTML page.)` and process them again, so that I can finally return a string as the fetch response.

Comment: looks like you will have to use javascript, to first read the form, and then ask for the other inputs based on that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share what you have tried so far with a code example?

Comment: @manas but I need to process the initial inputs in python.

Comment: @Jay I tried this with HTML instead of React using the render_template of flask every time I want to ask the inputs generating a bunch of HTML files

Comment: send the initial form data through JavaScript (to python backend), then once the reply comes, then show the appropriate input fields through JavaScript (in the same page).

Comment: @manas I did in this way and I got it working using conditional rendering but I used many fetch requests and I want to know if it's ideal? .. and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use JS on client side to handling user's first input to make next form/fields for him